# Form submitting missed field value (sometimes!) Android

Tags: android, jquery, forms, hidden-field, smartphone

I started to analyze my form which works fine for the last 3 years and found out that I loose 1% of my form submitions every day. It happens that the forms which submitted on Android(smartphone with resolution 320-450) doesn't pass any hidden or unhidden field values.

I searched the internet. No chances. It happens very rarely and only on smartphones. It was even hard to detect the case. The problem was discovered when I started to log serialized $_REQUEST. When form fails I get empty serialized array.

More info: I can see from my special software (video tracker) that user do fills the form and hits the button "submit".

Any idea or hint will be hightly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. I changed form "POST" method to "GET" method. Maybe there are some cheap not orginal mobile phones which don't allow/have restriction with post data. Sending data as "GET" solved the problem.

But still, the situation is weird.